# Mitigate the warning message "References to generic type Iterator<E> should be parameterized"?

Tags: java, compiler-warnings

```
  public static void updateCustomers(List custList) {
      Iterator itr = custList.iterator(); // line 1
      // other stuff
  }
```

Above code display warning message at line 1 i.e

> Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator
>   should be parameterized

To mitigate warning i have two options

Option1:-

```
   public static void updateCustomers(List<Object> custList) {
      Iterator<Object> itr = custList.iterator(); // line 1
      // other stuff
  }
```

Option2:-

```
 public static void updateCustomers(List<?> custList) {
      Iterator<?> itr = custList.iterator(); // line 1
      // other stuff
  }
```

Both options successfully wipe out the warning message but my question is which one is better and why?

**UPDATE:-**

i agree best is

```
public static void updateCustomers(List<CustomerInfo> custList) {
    Iterator<CustomerInfo> ite = custList.iterator(); // line 1
    // other stuff
}
```

but custList is not always going to contain CustomerInfo.

Comment: @R.J corrected the original one. Thanks

Comment: Its not possible to have anything else in your list then a CustomerInfo if you defined your method parameter like that. If you have different types, just pass two Lists. (by the way, I would also suggest to define the collection instead of just using List)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the OP's update is:

```
public static void updateCustomers(List<CustomerInfo> custList) {
    Iterator<CustomerInfo> ite = custList.iterator(); // line 1
    // other stuff
}
```

but then the OP says:

> but custList is not always going to contain CustomerInfo.

So, does `custList` potentially contain some arbitrary types unrelated to `CustomerInfo`? If so, then declaring the parameter `List<?> custList` is probably best. Elements coming out of the iterator will be `Object` and you'll have to do `instanceof` checks and downcasts to use them.

On other hand, does `custList` contain elements of some particular subtype of `CustomerInfo`? If the latter, then you can make the method itself generic, like so:

```
public static <T extends CustomerInfo> void updateCustomers(List<T> custList) {
    Iterator<T> ite = custList.iterator(); // line 1
    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: whats the difference btw List<?> custList and List<Object> custList?

Comment: If you're calling `updateCustomers`, you can pass a `List<CustomerInfo>` to a `List<?>` parameter but not a `List<Object>` parameter. If you're writing `updateCustomers`, you cannot safely add anything to a `List<?>` but you can add any object to a `List<Object>`. See http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#What%20is%20the%20difference for gory details.

Answer (score 0):

This is better:

```
public static void updateCustomers(List<Customer> custList) {
    Iterator<Customer> ite = custList.iterator(); // line 1
    // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure someone else can explain this better, but to put it to the point: If you are not defining a type the compiler has to figure out which kind of type he is dealing with. So if you define the type you have type safety. By the way, Object is still too general, dont you have a class named Customer?

EDIT: Thats what I suggest to do if you have two Lists with different types:

```
public static void updateCustomers(ArrayList<CustomerInfo> custList, ArrayList<Whatever> whateverList) {
   Iterator<CustomerInfo> ite = custList.iterator(); // line 1
   Iterator<Whatever> iterator = whateverList.iterator(); // line 2
   // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making the method parameterised?

```
public static <T> void updateCustomers(List<T> custList) {
    Iterator<T> ite = custList.iterator();
    // other stuff
}
```